# Showing whole page with else statement PHP

Tags: php

Im checking users on my website if they use vpn or not with php connected via API, my script working good, if user used vpn an status says : "is a VPN"

if user not using vpn than status says : "is not a VPN"

what i wanted in my script, is that if user do not using vpn whole page of HTML should displayed not a status say : "is not a VPN" and than if using vpn the status says : "is a VPN" normally

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$IP_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'; # Manual IP Address
$API_KEY = "";
$API_URL = 'https://vpnapi.io/api/' . $IP_ADDRESS . '?key=' . $API_KEY;

$response = file_get_contents($API_URL);
$response = json_decode($response);

if(!$response->security->vpn) {
    echo " is a VPN.\n";
} else {
    echo " is not a VPN.\n";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center; color: rgb(51, 204, 0);"><big
 style="font-weight: bold;"><big><big><br>
Test Working!!!</big></big></big></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as your code already does... Wrap what you want to happen in the `if` and `else` blocks so that it's simply within those blocks:

```
if($response->security->vpn) {
    echo " is a VPN.\n";
} else {

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center; color: rgb(51, 204, 0);"><big
 style="font-weight: bold;"><big><big><br>
Test Working!!!</big></big></big></div>
</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

Alternatively, as a matter of preference and readability, you can remove the `else` entirely and just conditionally *return* to end the script.  For example:

```
if($response->security->vpn) {
    echo " is a VPN.\n";
    return;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center; color: rgb(51, 204, 0);"><big
 style="font-weight: bold;"><big><big><br>
Test Working!!!</big></big></big></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding and you want the `if` condition to show the message *and* the page, while the *else* only shows the page?  If that's the case then what you have is simply a basic `if` condition to conditionally perform an operation:

```
if($response->security->vpn) {
    echo " is a VPN.\n";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center; color: rgb(51, 204, 0);"><big
 style="font-weight: bold;"><big><big><br>
Test Working!!!</big></big></big></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any way you look at it, the structure is always the same.  Operations that are conditionally performed (that is, only sometimes performed depending on some data) go in `if` or `else` blocks.

Answer (score -1):

A fairly simple change

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$IP_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'; # Manual IP Address
$API_KEY = "";
$API_URL = 'https://vpnapi.io/api/' . $IP_ADDRESS . '?key=' . $API_KEY;

$response = file_get_contents($API_URL);
$response = json_decode($response);

if(!$response->security->vpn) {
    echo " is a VPN.\n";
} else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center; color: rgb(51, 204, 0);"><big
 style="font-weight: bold;"><big><big><br>
Test Working!!!</big></big></big></div>
</body>
</html>
}
?>
```

Alternatively you could output the message as part of the page

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$IP_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'; # Manual IP Address
$API_KEY = "";
$API_URL = 'https://vpnapi.io/api/' . $IP_ADDRESS . '?key=' . $API_KEY;

$response = file_get_contents($API_URL);
$response = json_decode($response);
$msg = '';
if(!$response->security->vpn) {
    $msg = " is a VPN.";
} else {
    $msg = 'is not a VPN.';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center; color: rgb(51, 204, 0);">
    <strong><?php echo $msg; ?></strong>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```